# Firebase - how to grant permission to super user for read and write

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

How can i grant super user to certain user in firebase real time database to read others users data e.g. (This is for authenticated users only, no one else is allowed to read or write)

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "'SUPER_USERS_ID_HERE' === auth.uid",
      ".write": "'SUPER_USERS_ID_HERE' === auth.uid",
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can get the super user's UID from the Auth section of the Firebase console. For example:

```
".write": "'0d52a06d-3e0b-4106-b7aa-924866fb2bff' === auth.uid"
```

Note the apostrophes around the UID as well.

Comment: Hi Craig, This fails as you can not have multiple rules, have you tested it? fails on my end. How can i hard code specific uid on the rules? @Craigc

Comment: @AllyMakongo as far as I can see, this snippet looks valid. What do you mean "you can not have multiple rules"?

Comment: Still looks valid but it does not work as per firebase new docs. How can i insert a hard coded userid to compare? This give an error when i simulate @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Craig's answer assume you identify user userrs by knowing their uid. How would you like to identify super users?

Comment: Let me rephrase, when i write to database with the authenticated user its okay, user can write and read data. Now i want another user based on his/her own authentication to write on a previous authenticated user. I have asked google but apparently they are working on it. Probably should another feature to implement. Can't find any solution yet! The snippet looks valid only if you hard code the same authenticated user not just any user

Comment: Your question and title are worded poorly then. You want users to be able to read/write the data of the user who was logged in right before them? I can think of one way to do that. I'll update my answer if you update your question to be much more specific and detailed.